# Reactjs with history

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to handle history with reactjs, in such a way that the browser back and forward buttons work intuitively. Is there any examples of this, or general guidelines I should be following?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's not too much different than how you would handle history without React.js. What works well for me is this: I have a top-level component that holds the state of the app in `this.state`. I'm using *Backbone's router*, so when I get an event from the router (a URL was loaded or changed in some way), I call `setState` to update the top-level component's state. When I update the state myself, I make sure to also call the router's navigate method to update the URL. Seems to work pretty well: you can see an example from my little app at https://github.com/mjm/eats.

Comment: The whole `eats` repo is documented using `.litcoffee`, Awesome! Thanks for the resource!

Comment: how do you run this example locally?

Answer (score 6):

Another option with React is to use the React router component. It handles pushState for you and you can dynamically change the available routes as needed. It works with the same methodology as React does, as it is a react class itself. Check it out at:

https://www.npmjs.org/package/react-router-component

Comment: The only downside of this is that it seems to be server side only, am I correct? It doesn't seem to play well with a browser-based approach.

Comment: There is a newer component, seems to be more rapidly supported, npm install react-router does the trick. https://github.com/rackt/react-router   Try it out.

Answer (score 3):

In the React distribution there's an exemple folder with one being TodoMVC + Director.

[Flatiron Director](https://github.com/flatiron/director) is a router, so you'll have an exemple on how to use it in React.

Notice that Instagram is currently using Backbone router but they are planning to use Director (mostly because they can use the same router on client and server side and they don't need Backbone except the router)

Comment: Are they going to go with the Flatiron's data model too? trying to look for a good js model. still using backbone model atm.

Comment: @devric sorry I don't know but you can ask on IRC #reactjs freenode and Pete Hunt or Vjeux will tell you

Answer (score 1):

In general when it comes to client side route handing, As long as your URL always leads to one application state and one state only the back and forward-buttons will work fine, it shouldn't matter in your application *how* you reach a certain URL/State.

So if states in your app (not the React setState-state, just whatever state your app can be in) is always is reflected with a unique URL then you're all set.

Answer (score 1):

I [wrote a React mixin](https://github.com/leifdenby/jshistory_react_mixin) for using [history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/) to push the internal state of a React component to the browser's history.

The basic idea is to:

1. Register the React component to receive data from the browser history on page load. This is done with `bindToBrowserHistory`.
2. Call `saveState` at any point in the React component where you would like to save the state the browser's history.

```
var SimpleCategoryView = React.createClass({
  mixins: [HistoryJSMixin],
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { current_category: 0 }
  },
  handleCategoryChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({current_category: e.target.value});
    this.saveState();
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.bindToBrowserHistory();
  },
});
```

In this example I am using `handleCategoryChange` to handle when the user clicks a button to change the category, when this happens I want to remember the current state of the React component.

I wrote in some more detail about this mixin [here](http://leifdenby.svbtle.com/reactjs-and-browser-history-a-historyjs-mixin).

Answer (score 1):

Remember EmberJS has done a great work on routing. This react-nested-router has borrowed the technique from that and might help you out.https://github.com/rpflorence/react-nested-router

Answer (score 0):

[React Router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router) has worked really well for me. Super simple to use, with tons of bells and whistles if you need them.